# Why do I get notified when someone uses part of my name in a comment?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, comment-replies

I got a notification last night about [a question I did a retag on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353948/consume-soap-web-service-with-xamarin-forms) a while back. The notification was of someone commenting and using an @reply to the original poster.

The original poster's username is simply "Michael," and that is who the person leaving the comment was directing their comment. However, I got the ping for it.

I did some searching and found [this answer on Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/154928) which states:

> Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John. (Use the next rule to differentiate.)

Okay, that makes sense (I guess), but this logic is severely flawed.

1. The OP's name is literally "Michael" and the commenter used "@Michael". That should be all the logic ping needs to notify the right person. In this case, since the comment was directed towards the OP of the question, they'll get notified, but what if that wasn't the case?
2. Why would there be logic to loosely match someone up so sloppily like this? If someone wants to ping me, they can't be bothered to type one additional character (e.g. "I") for the autocomplete to finish?

---

The problems with @replies seem pretty buggy. I'm proposing changes to this logic so @replies don't get lost going to the wrong people. There is a search-as-you-type popup when doing @replies as it is and that should be enough to make is easy for someone to pick the right user to reply to.

Comment: I think you shot yourself in the foot by initially suggesting that edits should not making you pingable. I could see how people would downvote based on that. However, the rest of your concern seems reasonable. If someone who commented and is not the OP is named "Michael" then if  someone else intentionally wants to address *them*, they cannot do it if someone else with a user name that merely begins with "Michael" has made a comment after "Michael" did.

Comment: The OP will get a notification for any comment on his question and does not need to be pinged so it doesn't matter in this case that someone else got pinged.

Answer (score 11):

1. The OP (*and* the person @pinged) will always get notified of comments.
2. Because it's convenient, especially with usernames containing spaces.

I don't think utterly removing the "loose" matching is a good idea, as it allows users to skip portions of particularly long usernames.

The feature could be improved by making it look for a exact match, first. If an exact match isn't found, then the loose matching should be used.

For example:

> *"Look, I just commented!"* - Jack
>   *"Well then, so did I"* - Jackson

In this case, `@Jack` should notify the first user.
As it is right now, because the loose matching prioritizes the "newest" post over an exact match, "Jackson" gets the notification instead.